# How do we enforce privacy while providing tracing of provenance using multiple channels in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger Fabric v0.6, a supply chain app can be implemented that allows tracing of provenance and avoids double-spending (i.e., distributing/selling items more than it has) and thus avoids counterfeit.  As an example, when a supplier supplies 500 units of an item to a distributor, this data is stored in the ledger.  The distributor can distribute a specified quantity of an item to a particular reseller  by calling a "transfer" function.  The transfer function does the following:

- checks if the distributor has enough quantity of an item to distribute to a particular reseller (i.e., if quantity to transfer <= current quantity)
- updates the ledger (i.e., deducts the current quantity of the distributor and adds this to the current quantity of the reseller)

With this approach, the distributor cannot distribute more (i.e., double spend) than what it has (e.g., distributing counterfeit/smuggled items).

In addition, a consumer can trace the provenance (e.g., an item was purchased from reseller1, which came from a distributor, which came from a supplier) by looking at the ledger.

However, since it uses a single ledger, privacy is an issue (e.g., reseller2 can see the quantity of items ordered by reseller1, etc.)

A proposed solution to impose privacy is to use multiple channels in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.  In this approach, a separate channel/ledger is used by the supplier and distributor.  Similarly, a separate channel/ledger is used by the distributor and reseller1, and another separate channel/ledger for the distributor and reseller2.

However, since the resellers (i.e., reseller1 and reseller2) have no access the the channel/ledger of the supplier and distributor, the resellers have no idea of the real quantity supplied by the supplier to the distributor.  For example, if the supplier supplied only 500 quantities to the distributor, the distributor can claim to the resellers that it procured 1000 quantities from the supplier.  With this approach, double spending / counterfeiting will not be avoided.

In addition, how will tracing of provenance be implemented?  Will a consumer be given access to all the channels/ledgers?  If this is the case, then privacy becomes an issue again.

Given this, how can we use multiple channels in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 while allowing tracing of provenance and prohibiting double spending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no straight forward way of providing provenance across two different channels within Hyperledger Fabric 1.0. There few directions to support such scenarios:

1. First one is to have an ability to keep portions of the data of the ledger and provide discrete segregation within the channel, the work item described here: [FAB-1151](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151).
2. Additionally there is proposal of adding support for private data while maintaining the ability to proof existence and ownership of claimed asset was posted in mailing [list](https://lists.hyperledger.org/pipermail/hyperledger-fabric/2017-July/001277.html).

What you can do currently is to leverage application side encryption to provide privacy and keep all related transactions on the same channel, e.g. same ledger (pretty much similar to approach you had back in v0.6).

Answer (score 5):

As Artem points out, there is no straightforward way to do this today.

Chaincodes may read across channels, but only weakly, and they may not make the content of this read a contingency of the commit.  Similarly, transactions across channels are not ordered, which creates other complications.

However, it should be possible to safely move an asset across channels, so long as there is at least one trusted participant in both channels.  You can think of this as the regulatory or auditor role.

To accomplish this, the application would essentially have to implement a mutex on top of fabric which ensures a resource does not migrate to two different channels at once.

Consider a scenario with companies A, B, and regulator R.  A is known to have control over an asset Q in channel A-R, and B wants to safely take control over asset Q in channel A-B-R.

To safely accomplish this the A may do the following:

1. A proposes to lock Q at sequence 0 in A-R to channel A-B-R.  Accepted and committed.
2. A proposes the existence of Q at sequence 0 in A-B-R, endorsed by R (who performs a cross channel read to A-R to verify the asset is locked to A-B-R).  Accepted and committed.
3. A proposes to transfer Q to B in A-B-R, at sequence 0.  All check that the record for Q at sequence 0 exists, and includes it in their readset, then sets it to sequence 1 in their writeset.

Green path is done.  Now, let's say instead that B decided not to purchase Q, and A wished to sell it to C. in A-C-R.  We start assuming (1), (2), have completed above.

3. A proposes to remove asset Q from consideration in channel A-B-R. R reads Q at sequence 0, writes it at sequence 1, and marks it as unavailable.
4. A proposes to unlock asset Q in A-R.  R performs a cross channel read in A-B-R and confirms that the sequence is 1, endorses the unlock in A-R.
5. A proposes the existence of Q at sequence 1 in A-C-R, and proceeds as in (1)

Attack path, assume (1), (2) are done once more.

- A proposes the existence of Q at sequence 0 in A-C-R.  R will read A-R and find it is not locked to A-C-R, will not endorse.
- A proposes to remove the asset Q from consideration in A-R after a transaction in A-B-R has moved control to B.  Both the move and unlock transaction read that value at the same version, so only one will succeed.

The key here, is that B trusts the regulator to enforce that Q cannot be unlocked in A-R until Q has been released in A-B-R.  The unordered reads are fine across the channels, so long as you include a monotonic type sequence number to ensure that the asset is locked at the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in **v1.2**,

> Fabric offers the ability to create **private data collections**,
>   which allow a defined subset of organizations on a channel the ability
>   to endorse, commit, or query private data **without having to create a
>   separate channel**.

Now in your case, you can create a subset of your reseller data to be private to the particular entity without creating a separate channel.
More Info refer: [Fabric Doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/private-data/private-data.html).

Comment: If you make data private - it becomes unverifiable. If it is verifiable - it is no longer private.